# Why is Mar son of Ravina's prayer commonly recited after Amidah?

Tags: tefilla, minhag, shemoneh-esrei, tractate-brachot

[Berachot 16b-17a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.16b.18?lang=bi) lists a number of prayers that various *amoraim* recited at the end of Amidah.

Common practice (at least in the Ashkenazi and Edot Mizrach *siddurim* that I've seen) seems to be to recite (a text based on) [the prayer of Mar son of Ravina](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.17a.4?lang=bi) (*Elokai netzor*).

**Are there sources that discuss why it was that reciting specifically his prayer ultimately became the widespread custom (as opposed to the prayer of one of the other *amoraim*)?**

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.122.6

Comment: Note that some of the other ones are accepted in other prayer concepts. E.g. Rav in Birchas Hachodesh, Rebbe in Birchos Hashachar, Rava in Vidui.

Comment: For more prayers check out Yerushalmi 4.2